# Use input from a file for a command

Tags: bash, command

I want to use the mac address stored in a file in aireplay-ng command. I want this command to be executed once with each mac address in the file. Can you please tell me how to do it?

```
sudo aireplay-ng -1 0 -e VMC_AP -a  D4:4C:24:2B:EE:80 -h CC:AF:78:B3:E5:0F mon0 --ignore-negative-one
```

I want `-h  CC:AF:78:B3:E5:0F` to be replaced by different mac address stored in a file .

Thank you!

Comment: my boss says the same to me sometimes...  more info pls! better with your codes buddy.

Comment: I've posted the code:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming **mac.txt** is the file where all mac addresses are (one per line), you can use the following:

```
while read mac
do 
    sudo aireplay-ng -1 0 -e VMC_AP -a  D4:4C:24:2B:EE:80 -h $mac mon0 --ignore-negative-one  &
done < mac.txt
```